# GKE stuck at autorepairing and not able to add the nodepools

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Recently I faced an issue in my Kubernetes cluster on GCP,
From all services which is running in the my cluster, one of the service used the node memory out of limit and Node get crashed, Application node status changed to **NotReady** status due to the pressure in memory and `GKE` started **auto repairing** the node, meanwhile I was not able to add new nodes in GKE cluster as the cluster was on autorepair and GCP UI disabled all the options to add newer nodepool. Still the cluster is in auto-repairing continuously. Also I already enabled the node auto-scaling feature in my cluster, though it did not add new node.
I wonder what should be done to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's always best practice to set resource limits and requests to the workload so it won't take much resources from Node.

Just extra details on when a node will be a candidate for repair if any of the following conditions are met.

- The node has been in an unhealthy state for the past few minutes, typically 10-15 minutes
- The disk of the node has reached full capacity.
- There were GPUs/TPUs that could not be allocated.
- The node reports problematic GCFSD (Google Container File System daemon)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do if GKE is disabling the option to add new node pool instead you can follow other best practices first.

You can first add the resource **limit** and **request** to the workload so won't take much resources of Node.

```
requests:
  cpu: "150m"
  memory: "80Mi"
limits:
  cpu: "1"
  memory: "1024Mi"
```

Read more : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

You can also search using the **Nodeselector** and **affinity** to schedule specific PODs on specific nodes.

You can also check for QoS class once.