# GKE Clusters no indication within metrics or logs after failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using Google Cloud Platform and our GKE clusters has had multiple "node auto repair" events occur within the last 48 hours, and we can find no indication within the metrics, nor in the logs, that might explain why the control plane required it to do so.

How can I debug this ?

No support from Google team

Comment: Do you have master logs enabled for your cluster?

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth to check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77940720/16425408)

Also, by any chance if you have enabled master logs for your cluster check with `NodeNotReady` keyword or track node's different metrics in metric explorer.

I have came across many situations where users fail to apply resources limit and that results in such node behaviour

Comment: We are already checking the logs and are not able to find out why the node repair was required.

Comment: Regular logs will not be of much use, but the kube-controller-manager logs will provide a clearer picture. I would recommend contacting GCP support, as they likely have more visibility into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the gcloud command below to see the repair events

```
gcloud container operations list
```